# All subsets of a set in clojure

Tags: clojure, set, subset, combinatorics

I wish to generate all subsets of a set except empty set

ie

```
(all-subsets #{1 2 3}) => #{#{1},#{2},#{3},#{1,2},#{2,3},#{3,1},#{1,2,3}}
```

How can this be done in clojure?

Comment: Usually the powerset includes the empty set too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to: [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n/20916633#20916633)

```
(defn comb [k l]
  (if (= 1 k) (map vector l)
      (apply concat
             (map-indexed
              #(map (fn [x] (conj x %2))
                    (comb (dec k) (drop (inc %1) l)))
              l))))


(defn all-subsets [s]
  (apply concat
         (for [x (range 1 (inc (count s)))]
           (map #(into #{} %) (comb x s)))))
```

; (all-subsets #{1 2 3})
; (#{1} #{2} #{3} #{1 2} #{1 3} #{2 3} #{1 2 3})

Comment: Probably the only real quibble I have with this answer is the use of ones and lower case L's as variable names. Had to squint a bit at it.

Answer (score 14):

In your `:dependencies` in `project.clj`:

```
[org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.7"]
```

At the REPL:

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as combinatorics])

(->> #{1 2 3}
  (combinatorics/subsets)
  (remove empty?)
  (map set)
  (set))
;= #{#{1} #{2} #{3} #{1 2} #{1 3} #{2 3} #{1 2 3}}
```

`clojure.math.combinatorics/subsets` sensibly returns a seq of seqs, hence the extra transformations to match your desired output.

Comment: I'm hoping for a simple implementation and not rely on a library

Comment: @zcaudate: Clojure is a library language. A hand-written implementation to solve a general problem like this is never a good idea and simply not good practice, except for learning purposes. Relying on an official library like `math.combinatorics` has no trade-offs and usually outperforms everything you could do by hand by a far degree. Also you can expect it to be improved by people dedicated to the problem if improvements are possible.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a concise, tail-recursive version with dependencies only on clojure.core.

```
(defn power [s]
   (loop [[f & r] (seq s) p '(())]
      (if f (recur r (concat p (map (partial cons f) p)))
            p)))
```

If you want the results in a set of sets, use the following.

```
(defn power-set [s] (set (map set (power s))))
```

Answer (score 3):

@zcaudate: For completeness, here is a recursive implementation:

```
(defn subsets
  [s]
  (if (empty? s)
    #{#{}}
    (let [ts (subsets (rest s))]
      (->> ts
           (map #(conj % (first s)))
           (clojure.set/union ts)))))

;; (subsets #{1 2 3})

;; => #{#{} #{1} #{2} #{3} #{1 2} #{1 3} #{2 3} #{1 2 3}} (which is correct).
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight variation of @Brent M. Spell's solution in order to seek enlightenment on performance consideration in idiomatic Clojure.

I just wonder if having the construction of the subset in the loop instead of another iteration through `(map set ...)` would save some overhead, especially, when the set is very large?

```
(defn power [s]
    (set (loop [[f & r] (seq s) p '(#{})]
         (if f (recur r (concat p (map #(conj % f) p)))
             p))))

(power [1 2 3])
;; => #{#{} #{3} #{2} #{1} #{1 3 2} #{1 3} #{1 2} #{3 2}}
```

It seems to me `loop` and `recur`is not lazy. 
It would be nice to have a lazy evaluation version like Brent's, to keep the expression elegancy, while using laziness to achieve efficiency at the sametime.

This version as a framework has another advantage to easily support pruning of candidates for subsets, when there are too many subsets to compute. One can add the logic of pruning at position of `conj`. I used it to implement the prior algorithm for "Frequent Item Set".

Answer (score 1):

This version is loosely modeled after the [ES5 version on Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Functional_.28ES_5.29). I know this question seems reasonably solved already... but here you go, anyways.

```
(fn [s]
  (reduce 
    (fn [a b] (clojure.set/union a 
      (set (map (fn [y] (clojure.set/union #{b} y)) a))))
#{#{}} s))
```